# Dockerize laravel queue:listen

Tags: php, laravel, docker, queue, laravel-5

I have docker image that should run laravel queue. In the image i have command `php artisan queue:listen` but when i start the container nothing happens and the container runs.

Here is the base image

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

COPY ./000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf


RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
      git \
      cron \
      libpq-dev \
      postgresql-client \
      libfreetype6-dev \
      libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
      libmcrypt-dev \
      libpng12-dev \
      php5-gd \
          && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt \
          && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
          && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql && docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN a2enmod rewrite
```

and here is the image

```
COPY ./ /var/www/html

RUN mv /var/www/html/.env.cloud.dev /var/www/html/.env

RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/bootstrap && chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/storage && chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/app/Base

RUN php artisan optimize

RUN php artisan key:generate

CMD ["php", "artisan", "queue:listen"]
```

I have one more image that is loaded in the final image but that image is only for installing composer. Maybe i'm missing a library?

Comment: 1) what do you see when you do 'docker ps'? 2) did you try getting a shell into the container, and launching queue:listen manually?

Answer (score 4):

If the code you pasted is real code then you have typo:

```
CMD ["php", "artisan", "quedue:listen"]
```

should be `queue` and not `quedue`

Comment: Sry i forgot that typo. i made a typo to see if it falis. My real code is without typo

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to do something like a

```
docker exec -t (container) php artisan queue:listen
```

after everything is running?